How can i implement one android studio project in another using importBuild?
Rn im trying to build multi-module android app and i need help to implement dependency on my other project in my current project
I included submodule using git submodule add and now my proj structure looks like this:
-EffectiveMobileTest2domain
  -domainApp
    -build.gradle.kts
  -EffectiveMobileTest2data
    -dataApp
      -build.gradle.kts
    -settings.gradle.kts
    -build.gradle.kts
  -settings.gradle.kts
  -build.gradle.kts

so settings.gradle.kts at EffectiveMobileTest2domain looks like that:
rootProject.name = "EffectiveMobileTest2domain"
include(":domainApp")
includeBuild("EffectiveMobileTest2data")

and im trying to implement dependency at build.gradle.kts (:domainApp) like that:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation("com.mishbanya:dataApp")
}

my build.gradle.kts (:dataApp) has:
android {
    namespace = "com.mishbanya.effectivemobiletest2data"
...

but i get

Failed to resolve: com.mishbanya:dataApp

what and how i need to implement in build.gradle.kts (:domainApp) ??
